# Command names present in Quick access toolbar

Tags: c#, vba, excel

Is it possible to get all command names present in quick access toolbar of excel 2010
 I'm trying to get it in winforms and Console application

I just want to print names like (copy ,paste ,screenshot,save etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bizarre yet interesting request :)

I have been thinking about this question for quite sometime now. AFAIK (and I could be wrong) but you cannot interact with QAT directly like the way you want to. **HOWEVER** I have an alternative to suggest. See the snapshots.

Click on "More Commands"

[image]

You will be presented with the "**Excel Options**" dialog box.

Under "**Customizations**", select "**Export all customizations**"

[image]

Save the file. Remember the location where you are saving it. The file will be saved as `FILENAME.exportedUI`

If you open this file in notepad then it would look something like this.

[image]

Now using RegEx, you can simply find the names of the menus. Whether you want to use C# or VBA for RegEx, I leave that option to you.

HTH